# Rails puts to console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, console

In my Rails app, there are some cases where code is being outputted with the puts command (for debugging purposes). Is there anyway to follow this output in the rails console (with the rails c command)? Or is there any other way to debug/view logs in the rails console?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails.logger is the best solution,one more think i want to add,if you want separate log file you could use like this

```
def read(args)    
 unless args.blank?
   cache_key= self.get_cache_key(args)
 end
 logger = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/cache_read.log")
 logger.error("cache read scope == #{cache_key.to_s}")
end
```

so cache_read.log file having only this method log only.

Answer (score 5):

For debugging, use [Rails.logger](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger) instead of `puts`. For example:

```
Rails.logger.info "Some debugging info"
```

This will be logged to a log file in `rails_app_root/log` directory. If you are running in development environment locally, it will be logged to `rails_app/log/development.log` file.

Now, to see the log as they come in you can use `tail` command, like this:

```
tail -f log/development.log
```

Hope it helps.